# LINQ to SQL Order of Evaluation of a Boolean

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following code which generates a null reference exception when I provide a null argument to the `PerformQuery` method.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }
}
public class TableObject
{
    // This is a Guid stored as a string
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
public DataContext context;
public TableObject PerformQuery(MyObject obj)
{
    return context.TableObjects.FirstOrDefault(tableObject =>
        obj != null &&
            // Why is this side of the condition being evaluated if obj is null?
        string.Equals(obj.Guid.ToString(), tableObject.Hash));
}
```

I'm sure that the `TableObject` is not null. How could it? and It's property `Hash` is not nullable, so it shouldn't be null either (though I've checked both for null with no improvement).

I have solved the issue myself by calculating the Guid string that I am searching fore before executing the query, but I'm curious as to why LINQ continues to evaluate the conditional even if `obj` is null. Is this because of LINQ to SQL optimizations that the booleans are not evaluated in the same order as if it was a traditional `if else` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because linq-to-sql tries to translate the *whole* expression into SQL. So the null object reference occurs during this translation. You can tell because no SQL is even sent to the database.

The solution is to evaluate `obj.Guid` before you compose the query (as in @ps2goat's answer, but the reason is slightly different).

Comment: Thanks I was looking for the _reason_ not the solution I already had.

Answer (score 6):

You should evaluate local objects before entering the LINQ to SQL query.  The database has no way to know if your object is null.

```
 public TableObject PerformQuery(MyObject obj) {
        if (obj == null) {return null;}

        // also pull this out of the LINQ logic.
        string objGuid = obj.Guid.ToString();

        return context.TableObjects.FirstOrDefault(tableObject => 
            string.Equals(objGuid, tableObject.Hash));
    }
```